# Python syntax for listing GCPs in gdal.Translate?

Tags: python, gdal

I would like to use gdal.Translate to add several GCPs to a Tiff image, but I don't know the correct syntax to do this. `help(gdal.TranslateOptions)` tells me that I need to use the 'GCPs' kwarg and that this should be a list of GCPs. Does anyone know how I would add the GCPs as a list?

I have done this using the command line and gdal_translate, which is very straightforward, but I would ideally like to do this with Python because the remainder of my code for my project is in Python.

This is what I did in the command line:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 0 0 -4.717259 52.711651 -gcp 127 0 3.305363 51.733681 -gcp 0 31 -4.992584 51.498657 -gcp 127 31 2.828687 50.546162 -gcp 50 21 -1.762230 51.575226 "C:\PATH_TO_TIF\sds_001.tif" "Output_test.tif”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's interested, I ended up just doing it through the command line with the following while in the source directory, looping over all my Tiffs:

```
for %i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 0 0 -4.717259 52.711651 -gcp 127 0 3.305363 51.733681 -gcp 0 31 -4.992584 51.498657 -gcp 127 31 2.828687 50.546162 -gcp 50 21 -1.762230 51.575226 %i %i.GCP.tif
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing because the Python bindings expect the arguments in a different order compared to the command line tool.

```
import gdal

# x, y, lon, lat
gcps = [
    (0, 0, pt1.x, pt1.y),
    (width, 0, pt2.x, pt2.y),
    (width, height, pt3.x, pt3.y),
    (0, height, pt4.x, pt4.y),
]

ds = gdal.Open('filename.bmp')
gdal.Translate(
    'filename.tiff',
    ds,
    outputSRS='EPSG:4326',
    GCPs=[gdal.GCP(x, y, 0, pixel, line) for (pixel, line, x, y) in gcps],
)
```